# Wordpress - domain name continually repeats in url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, domain-name

I had a successfully working Wordpress website at nicholasolsen.ca and I was trying to change a url through the htaccess but wasn't working so I reset my permalinks to 'plain path' and it all broke so I put them back to 'post name' and then it did what it's doing now.

nicholasolsen.ca/nicholasolsen.ca/nicholasolsen.ca/nicholasolsen.ca/nicholasolsen.ca/nicholasolsen.ca/nicholasolsen.ca/ ...

I set the htaccess back to standard original and its still broken.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache since resetting your `.htaccess` ?

Comment: yes.  First thing I did.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on Wordpress, but I think somewhere, the index file is redirecting to ./nicholasolsen.ca, and it redirects to ./nicholasolsen.ca/nicholasolsen.ca and so on. A redirect is missing an HTTP://, possibly? It thinks the website name is a folder/file on the website. BTW, on my phone, the website shows up fine...

I hope you can fix it. If all else fails, restore the files to a new wordpress installation.